# Добавить элемент со страницы на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сайт на WordPress (если это нужная информация), мне нужно с разных страниц добавлять на единую страницу блоки HTML, хотел это сделать с помощью jQuery

```
var $list = $('.programm-list').html();
$($list).appendTo($(".prices-common"));
```

и пробовал так

```
var $list = $('.programm-list');
$($list).appendTo($(".prices-common"));
```

Но вывод `console.log($list);` говорит, что нет такого объекта, то есть JavaScript не видит другие страницы, по всей видимости. Есть какой-то способ сделать это (или же обратный порядок, раскидать с одной страницы на разные эти блоки) на франтенде?

Comment: `localStorage`/`sessionStorage`

Comment: _> с разных страниц_ - у вас там фреймы что ли?

Comment: @mymedia да я даже не знаю что такое феймы) нет, прайслист общий и для каждой услуги свои цены, и нужно реализовать, что цены были зависимы на этих страницах.

Comment: @Igor о таком не слышал, буду гуглить, спасибо

Comment: @YaroslavSaenko начните с простого - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: @Igor окей, спасибо

Comment: @Yaroslav, тут дело в том, что если у вас эти разные страницы берутся с разных сайтов (доменов), это запрещено (при условии отсутствия разрешения от этих самых сайтов). См. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: @mymedia нет, нет, сайт один, разные страницы, но console.log на старнице где этот объект содержится мне все показывает, а на странице куда его нужно закинуть показывает undefined

Comment: я думаю тут нужно код самого сайта редактировать, закидывать данные одной страницы на другую через javascript очень странно. можно просто их уже с сервера отправить в нужном виде.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин я не умею в бэкенд) с джаваскриптом тоже на старте, но уже кое что да умею, так что думал и это реализовать скриптом

Comment: У вас `woocommerce`? С помощью чего реализованы товары? Или просто статика(чистая вёрстка)? Если у вас данные тянутся из БД - вам просто надо выводить товары там где нужно и как нужно. Вопрос уже будет больше по пхп

Comment: @Klimenkomud нет, магазина там нет, просто прайс, без функионала

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript и JQuery ваш вопрос не решит, так как эти технологии работают уже на клиенте с тем кодом который возвратит сервер. Откуда ваша клиентская страница узнает о других страницах? Да, конечно если вы туда уже заходили эти данные можно положить в localStorage, а если не заходили? Конечно можно их и через Ajax подгрузить, но это будет скорее всего как начинать строить дом с крыши... конечно можно, но будет очень сложно и криво. И всё-равно для Ajax потребуется серверный код.

Вам необходимо править код самого серверного скрипта, который выдаёт вам страницы. Что бы он выдавал уже с учётом данных о других страницах товарах.

Comment: окей, спасибо. То есть для реализации local.storage мне нужно посетить все необходимые страницы?

Comment: @YaroslavSaenko но вы же не можете требовать от посетителей сайта что бы они посещали все эти страницы?

Comment: ну это понятно, я это и спрашивал. Я не знаю как локал сторэдж работает. Спасибо

Comment: @YaroslavSaenko JavaScript (localStorage) работает на клиенте когда страница уже загружена в браузер, а вам необходимо что бы она была собрана ещё до браузера, то есть на стороне сервера